# Calculate the center point of the highest density of xy points

Tags: javascript, arrays, coordinate-systems

I have a square grid (200 x 200). I would like users to be able to vote on their next desired position of an object in this space. When a user votes I add the XY position to an array.

Currently to find the "winning" position I just take an average of X and an average of Y, but what I've found is the winning position tends to gravitate around the middle of the area (naturally as it's an average!).

[image: Average]

*White = votes, Yellow = "winning" XY point*

What I'd prefer is if it found the densest area of votes, and chose a point in the middle of that.

I.e single scattered votes don't pull the winning position too far from the dense area like an average does.

Is that possible?

*Example array*

```
[ { x: 39, y: 28 },
  { x: 69, y: 33 },
  { x: 51, y: 51 },
  { x: 14, y: 63 },
  { x: 75, y: 140 },
  { x: 171, y: 68 },
  { x: 140, y: 53 },
  { x: 173, y: 150 },
  { x: 123, y: 179 },
  { x: 103, y: 150 },
  { x: 145, y: 119 },
  { x: 92, y: 85 },
  { x: 58, y: 49 },
  { x: 28, y: 65 },
  { x: 41, y: 39 },
  { x: 46, y: 41 },
  { x: 49, y: 51 },
  { x: 43, y: 55 },
  { x: 35, y: 48 },
  { x: 29, y: 31 },
  { x: 68, y: 22 },
  { x: 58, y: 39 } ]
```

Comment: @Igor don't just troll the guy if you didn't get the question... for the rest of us is pretty clear what he wants... of curse I up-voted this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I'm not posting just an idea but I'm posting actual code. Hope you can see if it works for you.

Your problem basically falls into the realm of cluster analysis. You want to identify the different groups of data present in your dataset and which form a cluster. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis

Lucky for you, this problem has already a few method to be solved, and there's even an NPM package that allows you to execute some of the well know cluster analysis tools.

I have chosen DBSCAN for solving your set of points, feel lucky to give another algorithm a try if you feel you need something else. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN

I have used the density-clustering library from NPM. https://github.com/LukaszKrawczyk/density-clustering

The arbitrary parameters given to **DBSCAN** were **20** for the neighbourhood radius and **5** for the minimum number of point to be considered a "cluster"

And the code is a modified version of the example given in the github page of the NPM package.

```
var sample = [ { x: 39, y: 28 },
  { x: 69, y: 33 },
  { x: 51, y: 51 },
  { x: 14, y: 63 },
  { x: 75, y: 140 },
  { x: 171, y: 68 },
  { x: 140, y: 53 },
  { x: 173, y: 150 },
  { x: 123, y: 179 },
  { x: 103, y: 150 },
  { x: 145, y: 119 },
  { x: 92, y: 85 },
  { x: 58, y: 49 },
  { x: 28, y: 65 },
  { x: 41, y: 39 },
  { x: 46, y: 41 },
  { x: 49, y: 51 },
  { x: 43, y: 55 },
  { x: 35, y: 48 },
  { x: 29, y: 31 },
  { x: 68, y: 22 },
  { x: 58, y: 39 } ];


/* Transform your dataset to the format expected by the library */
var dataset = [];

for(var i=0; i<sample.length; i++){
   dataset.push([sample[i].x, sample[i].y]);
}

var clustering = require('density-clustering');
var dbscan = new clustering.DBSCAN();
/* parameters: 
    20 - neighborhood radius
    5 - number of points in neighborhood to form a cluster
*/
var clusters = dbscan.run(dataset, 20, 5);

if(clusters.length > 0){

    /* Find the biggest cluster */
    var biggestCluster = clusters[0];

    for(i=1;i<clusters.length;i++){

        if(cluster[i].length > biggestCluster.length){
            biggestCluster = cluster[i];    
        }
    }

    /* The output of the library contains the indexes of the points in the cluster, not the coordinates, so we need to get the point from the dataset */
    var clusterPoints = [];
    var sumx = 0;
    var sumy = 0;

    for(i=0;i<biggestCluster.length;i++){
       var point = dataset[biggestCluster[i]];
       clusterPoints.push(point);

       /* It's also a good opportunity to cumulate x and y so we can get the average */
       sumx+=point[0];
       sumy+=point[1];
    }

    console.log('Cluster:', clusterPoints);    
    console.log('Center:', sumx/clusterPoints.length, sumy / clusterPoints.length);
}
else{
    console.log('No clusters');
}
```

The output from this program will be:

```
Cluster: [ [ 51, 51 ], [ 58, 49 ], [ 41, 39 ], [ 46, 41 ], [ 49, 51 ], [ 43, 55 ],  [ 35, 48 ],  [ 58, 39 ], [ 69, 33 ],  [ 39, 28 ], [ 29, 31 ], [ 28, 65 ], [ 68, 22 ] ]

Center: 47.23076923076923 42.46153846153846
```

Comment: Very nice thank you, would you recommend I fall back to using an average like in my original example if no clusters can be found?

Comment: @GreenGiant yeah I guess so... I mean, you gotta do what fits to your situation. What would a human do, if in a group no one seems to find a consensus about a (democratic) decision, like in your example?

Comment: This works perfectly thank you! http://f.cl.ly/items/090q1I1g460m1e2V3y2G/Screen%20Shot%202015-10-29%20at%2015.40.30.png

Answer (score 4):

A solution can be to compute for every point the sum of distances from it to all other points. The point with the smallest sum should be the center of the area with the highest density.

Comment: That is actually a very good version - i doubt that its fast but it does the job the proper way, and you'll probably only have to run it once. Have my upvote!

Comment: An interesting idea, I'm not too bothered about speed, I'd only have 700 entries at absolute maximum, on average I imagine 100. Would you calculate the X from all over X's, then Y from all other Ys and add X + Y for each point to get it's "sum of distances"?

Comment: The distance between two points can be computed using this formula: d(A(x1, y1), B(x2, y2)) = sqrt((x2 - x1)^2 + (y2 - y1)^2). You need to apply this formulla for each point individually, which means you can't add all X values and all Y values and compute distance using them.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, what does "d" "A" and "B" represent. Trying to plug this into my JS :)

Comment: d(A, B) is distance between points A and B. It is a mathematical equation. In order to transform it to a JS expression you need to use Math.sqrt and Math.pow methods

Comment: http://pastebin.com/iEdRFVB6 is what I have so far. Not producing quite what I'd expect though: http://f.cl.ly/items/2a3j1R1z1L3T0U3f1L29/Screen%20Shot%202015-10-29%20at%2014.51.16.png

Comment: I know you said not to add X + Y but it does seem to work a little better: http://f.cl.ly/items/1C0e2T0i3N413j130l0d/Screen%20Shot%202015-10-29%20at%2015.03.21.png (http://pastebin.com/Tgw1VWnB)

Comment: That looks merely coincidental. You should calculate the distances in pixels and you need X and Y seperately for that.

Answer (score 2):

That is actually really easy - combine all X's into 1 variable, and devide it by the number of X's. Same goes for y:

```
var totalX = 0, totalY = 0, avgX, avgY;

var coords = [ { x: 39, y: 28 },
    { x: 69, y: 33 },
    { x: 51, y: 51 },
    { x: 14, y: 63 },
    { x: 75, y: 140 },
    { x: 171, y: 68 },
    { x: 140, y: 53 },
    { x: 173, y: 150 },
    { x: 123, y: 179 },
    { x: 103, y: 150 },
    { x: 145, y: 119 },
    { x: 92, y: 85 },
    { x: 58, y: 49 },
    { x: 28, y: 65 },
    { x: 41, y: 39 },
    { x: 46, y: 41 },
    { x: 49, y: 51 },
    { x: 43, y: 55 },
    { x: 35, y: 48 },
    { x: 29, y: 31 },
    { x: 68, y: 22 },
    { x: 58, y: 39 } ]

for (var i = 0; i <= coords.length; i++) {
    totalX += coords[i].x;
    totalY += coords[i].y;
}

avgX = totalX / coords.length;
avgY = totalY / coords.length;
```

See it in action harrr (lol at ID): https://jsfiddle.net/harr55d2/

EDIT: This is not the right answer, sorry, misread your question.

What you could do though, is take this avarage place and from there calculate the distances to all points from there. You'll get some numbers from that. If you then calculate an avarage on the distance i think you'll get close to the point that you want to be.

Another method is to scan the 200x200 area in blocks of 20x20 (or something, maybe circles works best) and count all votes in there. The one with the most votes wins.

EDIT: Another method;

Take the distance for each vote from the avarage point. Then that is the  "score" or "weight" for a certain vote. You can then see that the votes closest to the avarage are being weighted the "best". If you catch my drift.

Comment: You actually compute the average point of whole area. What GreenGIant wants is to first get the most dense area and get the center of that area

Comment: Oooh crap, read it too fast. You're right. This is a whole different issue... A hard one.. Let me think about that..

Comment: Edited my answer with another method :)

Comment: Yer the first method is what I'm already doing, the second one sounds like an interesting and simple one!